# Why can't hyper-kahler manifolds have a connection with torsion?

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I have often seen the statement that Hyper-Kahler (HK) manifolds have torsion-free connections. In general relativity, however, one is usually taught that the connection is something that you can "choose". You might choose to use the Levi-Civita connection or not. Is it not possible for a HK manifold to choose a connection with torsion?

Comment: I suppose the question is what the putative connection with torsion is supposed to satisfy.  Presumably you would like it to be metric and preserving the hyperkähler structure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be understandably confused by a terminological inconsistency. People study so-called ***"[Hyper-Kähler manifolds with torsion](http://www.scielo.org.ar/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S0041-69322008000200012)"*** (a.k.a. HKT manifolds), which by definition have

- 3 complex structures $I$, $J$, $K$ satisfying the quaternion relations,
- a Riemannian metric $g$ Hermitian with respect to $I$, $J$ and $K$,
- a connection $\nabla$ relative to which $g$, $I$, $J$, $K$ are parallel,

such that: the tensor $g(\cdot,T(\cdot,\cdot))$ defined by the torsion $T$ of $\nabla$ is totally antisymmetric (a 3-form).

The irony, observed in the very [review](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1396267) of their introduction, is that unless $T=0$, these manifolds are ***not*** Hyper-Kähler in the classical sense of having their (Levi-Civita) holonomy contained in $\operatorname{Sp}(n)$.